# Send data to url using POST from C# code and display result as page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to send data to some url using POST but from C# code. Then I would like to display result as page.
By now I have some sample code, but it is'nt work properly as I want to.
I'm using asp.net mvc as client.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] response = client.UploadValues(url, 
        new NameValueCollection()
        { 
            {"desc", payment.Description},
            {"first_name", payment.FirstName},
            {"last_name", payment.FirstName},
            {"email", payment.Email},
            {"client_ip", payment.ClientIp},
        });

    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

    Response.Write(str);
}
```

Comment: What is not working as you expect? What do you expect and what is the actual result?

Comment: Well in 'str' I got whole html, but when I display it browser url still pointing to my page, not to page I would like display as result. Basically I need to redirect user to specified page as url with post data.

Comment: You cannot do that on the server. You have to make the request from the client and not from your MVC application. For example you could have an html `<form>` that will POST some hidden field values to the remote endpoint. If you are making the request from the server (as you are currently doing), it is impossible to redirect the client browser to the target url. A redirect means GET request.